# typeerror: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type "float

Tags: python

I am brand new to python (and programming in general) and I am following examples from 
Python Programming:
An Introduction to Computer Science
John M. Zelle, Ph.D.
Version 1.0rc2
Fall 2002
Obviously this is quite a bit out of date and I am using Python 3.3
I am typing in the exercise exactly as the book shows it (adding () around the print statements) but I keep coming up with the error. Here is a copy of what I input and the result when I tried to run the program. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> def main():
    print ("This program illustrates a chaotic function.")
    x=input ("Enter a number between 0 and 1:")
    for i in range(10):
        x= 3.9*x*(1-x)
        print (x)


>>> main()
This program illustrates a chaotic function.
Enter a number between 0 and 1:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 5, in main
    x= 3.9*x*(1-x)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>>
```

Comment: Well, even if you get the code of this and other examples to work, the book will probably be fraught with old and busted ways of doing things. Get a better, more recent book so you aren't ten years behind everyone else in terms of idioms, language features, libraries, etc.

Answer (score 4):

use `x=float(input ("Enter a number between 0 and 1:"))` as `input()` returns a string in python 3k not `float`:

```
>>> def main():
...     print ("This program illustrates a chaotic function.")
...     x=float(input ("Enter a number between 0 and 1:"))
...     for i in range(10):
...         x= 3.9*x*(1-x)
...         print (x)
... 
>>> main()
This program illustrates a chaotic function.
Enter a number between 0 and 1:.45
0.96525
0.13081550625
0.443440957341
0.962524191305
0.140678352587
0.47146301943
0.971823998886
0.106790244894
0.372005745109
0.911108135788
```